# Using anonymous functions in JavaScript IF statement

Tags: javascript, anonymous-function

How do I use an anonymous function in a if statement?  Please feel free to use the following as an example.  Thank you

```
if(function(){return false;} || false) {alert('true');}
```

Reference https://jsfiddle.net/san22xhp/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Wrap the function in parenthesis and then call it immediately after like this:

```
if((function(){return false;})() || false) {alert('true');}
```

Fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/Ar14/7p2ompod/

Comment: I swore I tried this first before posting this question, but evidently did not because it seems to work.  Thank you!  Do you know why it is required?

Comment: You have to invoke the function - no function will call itself only because it was declared.

Comment: You aren't calling the function in the if statement you're just defining it. By making it an IIFE (Immediately Invoked Function Expression) it'll run automatically.

Comment: Actually, what I originally tried was `if( (function(){return false;}) || false) {}`.  So the trailing `()` invokes it?

Comment: Exactly. Think of it as if you defined the function earlier and now are calling it like `function()`

Comment: Like any other function call you would do, like "alert( ... )" .. you are calling the function "alert" - the ( ) is invoking the function. Try to do the following: alert(alert); - this will give you back the actual code of the alert function but doesn't invoke it.

Comment: While probably a good idea for readability, the outside parenthesis around the anonymous function appears not to be required.

Answer (score 1):

Use the .call() method of the function constructor:

```
if(function(){return false;}.call() || false) { alert('true'); }
```

The advantage with this method is that you can pass variables to it, e.g.:

```
if(function(){return arguments[0] == 7;}.call(null, 7) === true) alert('yeah it is 7');
```

https://jsfiddle.net/f8175o2v/3/